# Clip Path with SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have created the below CSS Clip path with SVG. I would like to know that how to make it some unique shapes rather than the normal hexagonal mask? Also i would like to give border radius to the edges. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

http://ktdev.khaleejtimes.ae/bg/bg-shapenw1.html

```
.svg_pan {
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}



<svg class="svg-graphic svg_pan" width="180" height="200" viewBox="0 0 560 645" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <g>
       <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
          <polygon points="130,0 0,160 0,485 270,645 560,485 460,160" />
       </clipPath>
    </g> 
    <a xlink:href="#">
     <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="al-seef.jpg" />
    </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can't use a polygon for that. You'd have to use a path as it will involve more than straight lines.

Comment: Hi Paulie, Can you show me some examples, please?

Comment: Nope...that's for you to research. - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html

Comment: Have you considered using InkScape? It allows you to fully create and edit SVGs

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate the d attribute for a path - your polygon with rounded corners. In this case I'm using quadratic Béziers for the rounded corners. I hope it helps.

```css
.svg_pan {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-graphic svg_pan" width="180" height="200" viewBox="0 0 560 645" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

 <defs> 
 <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask-rounded"> 
  <path d="M147.996,8.725 Q130,0 117.388,15.522L12.612,144.478 Q0,160 0.000,180.000L0.000,465.000 Q0,485 17.206,495.196L252.794,634.804 Q270,645 287.512,635.338L542.488,494.662 Q560,485 554.118,465.884L465.882,179.116 Q460,160 442.004,151.275Z" />
   </clipPath>
  
  </defs>
    <a xlink:href="#">
     <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask-rounded)" height="650" width="650" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" />
    </a>
</svg>
```

This is a tool you may use to calculate the `d` attribute for the path using the points attribute of the polygon: https://enxaneta.github.io/SVG_polygon_with_rounded_corners/